# Using placeholder tags in non-django CMS pages

Tags: django, django-cms

In the Django CMS there's the `{% placeholder 'content' %}`. I tried to use it on a non-django-cms page, i.e., a detail-view page that comes from an apphook. However, when I switch to the structure view in the detail-view page and the placeholder does not seem to reflect. Is that's how it's supposed to work or is there a problem with my code? If it's how it's supposed to work is there a way to make placeholder appear in the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `{% placeholder` outside of CMS pages.

If you're on one of these pages, you can use a static placeholder. These will show the same content on any page where a static placeholder with the same name exists. So a good example of these is a footer, or header where you'd want it to be the same on all pages;

```
{% static_placeholder "footer" %}
```

Another thing you can use, good for your example of a detail page in an apphook, is a `PlaceholderField` on your models.

Take this example;

```
from django.db import models
from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = PlaceholderField('category_description')
```

In your template you can then render this placeholder and it'll behave like a standard placeholder on a cms page;

```
{% load cms_tags %}

{% render_placeholder category_instance.description language 'en' %}
```

You can find docs for `PlaceholderField` [here](https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/search.html?q=PlaceholderField&check_keywords=yes&area=default)